# Splitting of a String using query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I wrote a query which splits a string and show me as a value I want using SUBSTR

```
    SELECT SUBSTR ('imagelocation/r1.jpg', 15)   AS image_location  FROM dual
```

I am getting the output as r1.jpg but I only want the value to come as r1. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('imagelocation/r1.jpg',15,2) AS image_location FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUBSTR (
         'imagelocation/r1.jpg', 
         INSTR('imagelocation/r1.jpg', '/')+1,
         LENGTH('imagelocation/r1.jpg') - INSTR('imagelocation/r1.jpg', '.') - 1
       ) AS image_location  
FROM dual
```

**[SUBSTR Function in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj93082.html)**

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/21012)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more universal, regexp_replace might be of use.

```
SELECT 
regexp_replace('imagelocation/r1.jpg','^[^/]*/([^.]+).*$','\1') AS image_location 
FROM dual;
```